# Update Query not working in Fusion Table

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

I am updating the fusion table particular data using update query,but it is giving me the error :

```
   "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
```

This is my code so far:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
    url.push('sql=');
    var query = 'UPDATE'+'1joZ2Og1R7riq39OuiiYPoccj4AD9Y1oYXGi26cTF'+'SET display = yes'+'WHERE CFSAUID = A0A';
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    //url.push(encodedQuery);
    url.push('key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
    //script.src = url.join('');
    //var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   // body.appendChild(script);

    /* $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url.join(''),
  dataType: 'jsonp'
  });*/

$.ajax({
url : url.join(''), //Target URL for JSON file
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: encodedQuery,
async : false,
success : function(data){
   console.log(data);
},
error : function(xhr, status){

    console.log(status);
}

});
```

Can any one please let me know, the cause of the error.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: there must be a bug in google's quota system. from this morning google trends is giving me a quota-exceeded error on the 2nd search. it'll get fixed, i guess you'll just have to sit this one out

Comment: All write-queries on a FusionTable require Authentication via [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) , passing the key is not sufficient to authenticate a UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to comment on:

1. I am not sure whether your SQL query is right.  Say you have to leave space between "update" and the table ID, and you should have & between SQL and key
2. For the previous version of fusion table, it should be enough to perform query by passing a key obtained from OAuth2.  But the new version requires a developer API KEY to do so, I believe.

Good luck.

Ni